# load an existing mnesia db from files .DCD .DCL

Tags: database, erlang, load, dump, mnesia

I'm a newbie to Erlang and Mnesia.

I have a db with files .DCD .DCL schema.DAT in a folder, could someone tell me how to load into a mnesia node then dump it to text or csv?

Thanks guys